# How to convert a string as Oracle Connection in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a string which has connection information like
string sConn = "Data Source=testdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True"; and provider is System.Data.OracleClient
My requirement is to convert sConn as OracleConnection.

Please help.
p.s: I should not use  in web.config

Comment: did you read the manual to see what kind of connectionstring needs to be supported? did you look at www.connectionstring.com for example? Also not storing it in your web.config file is a bad thing to do - hard coding your connectionstring can be a security risk as well as not providing flexibility to change your conn string without having to change, recompile and deploy your code.

Comment: In web.config <connectionstrings> section i have encrypted connection info . <add name="ConString2" connectionString="weqwyscnskfjndefjdnhkvjdnvjkdnvfdjkvndjkvndfjkvndfjkvndfjkvndfjkvdnfkvdjkndfjnvdfjkvnk" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/> .  I want to create a connection as OracleConnection using above.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you going

```
string sConn = "Data Source=testdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True";

using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(sConn))
{
   //Do some work
}
```

Also you can read **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Comment: How to provide providername i.e Oracle.DataAccess.Client for the above connection.

Comment: Provide it in your connection string

Comment: string sConn = "Data Source=testdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True;provider Name=Oracle.DataAccess.Client";

using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(sConn))
{
   //Do some work
} Keyword not supported: 'provider name'.

Comment: Should be `providerName` not `provider Name` no space

Comment: string sConn = "Data Source=testdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True;providerName=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;";
                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(sConn); still am getting Keyword not supported: 'providername' error. can you please provide sample.

Comment: hmm.. it should work because that's exactly we use it in our products.. try removing the `providerName` and see if you can manage to connect to it

Comment: I am able to connect after removing providerName. Without providername i think connects thorugh default System.Data.OracleClient but instead i want to use Oracle.DataAccess.Client. how can i